# Developing new theories by transfinitely iterating the Godel sentence construction

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations, incompleteness

In Turing's Ph. D thesis "Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals", he writes of a simple way to use Gödel's incompleteness theorem to devise a transfinite sequence of new theories. The sequence proceeds via transfinite recursion as follows:

1. Begin with some theory $T_0$.
2. For any theory $T_n$ in the sequence, define the theory $T_n+1$ as the theory $T_n \cup G(T_n)$, where $G(T_n)$ is the Gödel sentence for the theory $T_n$.
3. For any limit ordinal $o$, the theory $T_o$ is the union of all previous theories, or $T_o = \cup \left\{T_n:n<o \right\}$

Turing then goes on to show that if one starts with $T_0 = PA$, that one does not get a complete theory $T_\alpha$ for any countable $\alpha$. I believe the same result holds for $T_0 = ZFC$

My question is, starting with either $PA$ or $ZFC$, what do we know about the first ordinal which *does* lead to a complete theory? Do we get a complete theory at $T_{\omega_1}$, for instance? This would be the first theory that is not recursively axiomatizable, and hence Gödel's theorem doesn't pertain to it. But is $\omega_1$ enough?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the incompleteness theorem, there is **no extension of PA** that is (a) complete *and* (b) consistent *and* (c) has a recursively enumerable set of axioms. Since every $T_\alpha$, if it exists at all, is an extension of PA, this hints that something can't be quite right here.

There's also a problem with speaking about $T_{\omega_1}$ at all, because such a theory would be one where you've added a new axiom uncountably many times -- but there are only countably many different formulas in the language of PA that you could conceivably add.

But there's a problem much before that, namely that your step 2 will stop working. Gödel's construction doesn't start with a theory as an abstract set of axioms, but takes an input a *particular algorithm* for recognizing the axioms in the set. So speaking about "the Gödel sentence" for $T_n$ requires you to have an algorithm for the theorems of $T_n$, and *that* stops being possible long before you reach $\omega_1$.

In order to describe $T_\alpha$, it appears that you'd need an algorithmic description of the structure of the ordinal $\alpha$, because that's how you constructed $T_\alpha$ itself. That stops being possible at all at $\omega_1^{CK}$, the [Church-Kleene ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Kleene_ordinal), which is smaller than $\omega_1$. So if you manage to construct $T_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, you no longer have a way of defining $T_{\omega_1^{CK}+1}$.

And even before $\omega_1^{CK}$ there's a possible problem, namely that some countable ordinals can have *many different* algorithmic descriptions where it may not be provable from any particular theory that they happen to describe the same ordinal. That is a problem when you reach a limit ordinal $\alpha$ and just describe $T_{\alpha}$ as a *mathematical* union of the previous theories. This doesn't offer any guidance about which algorithm for $\alpha$ you should use to construct a Gödel sentence that you can elevate to an axiom in $T_{\alpha+1}$. It is quite plausible that at some point  $T_{\alpha}$ itself cannot prove that the various algorithms for $\alpha$ are equivalent. From that point on, your process may proceed in several nondeterministic directions.

So the best you can possibly do -- and I'm far from sure there are not additional problems lurking here! -- is to define a procedure that takes a particular *ordinal notation* as input and produces a sequence of extensions of PA indexed by the ordinal you have a notation for. But different notations for the *same* ordinal may give you different extension sequences. At least all of the new axioms in *any* of the branches will be true in $\mathbb N$, so one could imagine taking the union of all the theories in all the branches, producing a new consistent theory that one could somewhat plausibly argue for calling $T_{\omega_1^{CK}}$. I don't immediately see a reason to expect this combined theory to be complete. It will definitely not be recursively axiomatized, so there's no $T_{\omega_1^{CK}+1}$ to continue with.

Comment: Arguably, once you've hit a non-computable ordinal you can add an oracle to your language. Of course, this would end up with an uncountable language once you've reached $T_{\omega_1}$.

Comment: @Asaf: I suppose you could do that, but I think we'd lose sight of the OP's intuitive plan by doing so. Once you accept having to extend the language of $T$ in order to describe $T$'s axioms, the "Gödel sentence for $T$" you end up producing will be a statement _about your oracle_ rather than a purely arithmetical claim, and it is not clear that we'll keep finding new _arithmetical_ truths that way.

Comment: In contexts where that is acceptable, we might as well replace Gödel's entire proof with: "Extend the language with a new constant symbol $c$, intuitively intended to represent the number forty-two. Then the sentence $c\ne 0$ is independent of your existing axioms (but is true in the intended application). Ta-dah!"

Comment: Oh, of course. That's a very sketchy approach to this. I'm just saying that this is a way of extending this "reasonably well" (from an intuitive point of view) to accommodate $T_{\omega_1}$ without breaking the cardinality argument.